# Client Server Cancel Process

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm working through a simple client-server example to get familiar with sockets and multi-threading. I have a simple GUI on the client side with two buttons- the first generates an n-bit sized prime number, the second cancels the operation of the first (because making an 8000 bit prime takes some time).

When users press "generate", the client will make a new thread. This thread creates two new threads, one to establish a connection to the server, and one to do nothing unless the GUI requests a "stop generating primes".

The server simply polls for connections. When a connection is made, it creates a new thread to generate the prime, then return that prime to the client.

Here is where I have a conceptual problem. If I wanted to implement the 'stop generating a prime' button on the client, how might I do it? My initial thought is to use the second thread to connect to the server using the same socket and tell it to 'stop'. How do I give the server a sense of ownership of the client requests? How can I get the server to say "okay, client A, I am currently running a thread to create a large prime, but I see now that you are requesting a cancellation." How do I give the server a sense of ownership to the requests?

Answer (score 0):

One way to start is to set your own request and response message for your client server communication. Because every new connection request to Server creates/uses a dedicated thread at Server site, you can continue communicating with server till the prime is calculated and pass STOP signalled if user clicks the Stop Button. Below is on high level, a way you can proceed with implementation.

T1 - Thread 1

**Client**

- T1(For UI 
  with Two Buttons) 
  On Start Button  -> Call ServerSocket and pass message "START PRIME n"
  On Stop Button   -> Call ServerSocket and pass message "STOP PRIME n"

  ```
  Request Messages 

  i.  START PRIME n
  ii. STOP PRIME n
  ```

**Server**

- T1(listens for client request) on Port 5000
  On request from client:

  1. Assign a new thread from thread Pool [Sample Chapter](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jcip-sample.pdf)

     ```
     Response Messages 

     i.  PRIME VAL <result>
     ii. STOP PRIME COMPLETE
     ```
  2. Thread T1 goes back to listening

Hope this helps!

Comment: So it's not necessary to make two threads for each client request on the server? Why do I not need one to listen for STOP and one to generate the prime?

Comment: You can create another Thread for STOP feature but I don't think its necessary. One of the disadvantages of creating another thread would be you have include a new include some kind of ID in your STOP request to tell client which previous request you want to stop